# Msbuild Property Function Contains on Metadata?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to check if metadata contains a string? For example:

```
<Test Include="@(Content)" Condition="%(Identity.Contains('AppxContentGroupMap.xml'))" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `WithMetadataValue` which is an `ItemFunction`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <TheItem Include="first">  
        <Plant>geranium</Plant>  
    </TheItem>  
    <TheItem Include="second">  
        <Plant>algae</Plant>  
    </TheItem>  
    <TheItem Include="third">  
        <Plant>geranium</Plant>  
    </TheItem>  
</ItemGroup>  

<Target Name="go">  
    <Message Text="MetaData:    @(TheItem->Metadata('Plant'))" />  
    <Message Text="HasMetadata: @(theItem->HasMetadata('Plant'))" />  
    <Message Text="WithMetadataValue: @(TheItem->WithMetadataValue('Plant', 'geranium'))" />  
    <Message Text=" " />  
    <Message Text="Count:   @(theItem->Count())" />  
    <Message Text="Reverse: @(theItem->Reverse())" />  
</Target>  

  <!--   
  Output:  
    MetaData:    geranium;algae;geranium  
    HasMetadata: first;second;third  
    WithMetadataValue: first;third  

    Count:   3  
    Reverse: third;second;first  
  -->
```

Comment: FWIW This doesn't answer the question, so I'm not sure why it was marked as the answer

Comment: You can compose the solution with this information - the author wanted a file with the FileName + Extension AppxContentGroupMap.xml